# getDependency for file of sentences

Tags: r, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to have dependency parser for each sentence. 
I tried coreNLP parsing for single sentence as

```
 library(coreNLP)
 initCoreNLP(mem="4g")
 x="I've been using Galaxy J5 for 2 years and it would never get heated while using even long."
 anno <- annotateString(x)
 ext<-getDependency(anno)
 extparse<-getParser(anno)
```

output: ext :
[image]

output:  extparse:

(ROOT\r\n  (S\r\n    (S\r\n      (NP (PRP I))\r\n      (VP (VBP 've)\r\n        (VP (VBN been)\r\n          (VP (VBG using)\r\n            (NP (NNP Galaxy) (NN J5))\r\n            (PP (IN for)\r\n              (NP (CD 2) (NNS years)))))))\r\n    (CC and)\r\n    (S\r\n      (NP (PRP it))\r\n      (VP (MD would)\r\n        (ADVP (RB never))\r\n        (VP (VB get)\r\n          (VP (VBN heated)\r\n            (PP (IN while)\r\n              (S\r\n                (VP (VBG using)\r\n                  (ADVP (RB even) (RB long)))))))))\r\n    (. .)))\r\n\r\n"

Type in dependency is giving correctly than parser But i want to implement this for a file that contains sentences ,How to implement coreNLP dependency for sentences .

I tried to do getdependency for multiple sentences at a time then I got it as vector form

[image]

how to get dependency for multiple sentences ??

here is my other question:
 how to analyse the parser data to extract all nouns and adjectives 
how to get each level of parser data separately so that each level could be processed

Any help is very precious as I was struct in this from many days